# How to solve NoReverseMatch at / (Error during template rendering) in django 3.2?

Tags: python, django

Here is the screenshots of error i am getting.

[image]

and

[image]

App Name is greeting_app
Now greeting_app/urls.py has the following code

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('about/<int:id>/', views.about, name="about"),
]
```

greeting_app/views.py has the following code

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from .models import basicinformation

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    information = basicinformation.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {"info":information})

def about(request, id):
    data = basicinformation.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request, 'about.html', {"data":data})
```

templates/index.html has the following code. I have included only the url part in index.html file.

```
<a href="{% url "about" data.id %}">Description</a>
```

Comment: Hi, in template for index using data.id while in context you passing info , I guess it should be in all.id as you are using info as context..

Comment: print data.id in your view and see if it has id

Answer (score 0):

`data.id` does not contain an ID. From the error message it contains `('',)` (or possibly `(",)` - it's hard to tell from an image. Please don't use images!).

You do  `for all in info`, then reference `all` in every other template line, then suddenly try and use `data.id`.

Since you haven't posted your whole template, it's hard to tell, but I suspect you want to use `all.id` in your URL here, and not `data.id`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add this to urls.py above urlpatterns

app_name=“ greeting_app”

2. Fix template url to this:
   <a href="{% url "greeting_app:about" data.id %}">Description